# Extended ASCII characters in Oracle Text blob not loading into HIVE correctly, showing as '?' instead

Tags: oracle, hive, binary, blob, sqoop

I have text blob data in oracle and I have imported using sqoop into HIVE in Binary.
Source blob is textual data with extended ASCII characters in it but in HIVE these special characters are not correct in HIVE.

I have tried by creating table using hcat -e and then loaded data in hive using sqoop with hcatalog.

I have tried using hcatalog.
Created table with Blob in oracle, then created equivalent table in HIVE but set as Binary instead of Blob.
Insert sample data with text and special charaters, then imported data using Sqoop.

```
Create table test_blob (col1 integer not null primary key, col2 blob); 

insert into test_blob 
     select rownum, utl_raw.cast_to_raw('Textþ03ý04ýString') from dual connect by level <= 100;
```

```
hcat -e "create table TEST_BLOB (col1 bigint, col2 binary) ;"
```

```
sqoop import --connect {connect-info} --table TEST_BLOB --hcatalog-table TEST_BLOB
```

```
select * from test_blob;
```

```
col1-col2
1-Text?03?04?String
```

My expectation is to load extended ASCII characters from source BLOB into HIVE binary or string correctly.

Comment: First of all, you shoud be using `CLOB` instead of `BLOB` for storing textual data. If you use `BLOB` - you should also provide the right encoding to transform binary data into text. Obviously, Oracle and Hive use different encoding, that's why you see incorrect results.

Comment: Thanks.
Converting from BLOB to CLOB takes time particularly when record count is in millions, I have tried few encodings but unable to resolve the issue.
Could you please suggest the best encoding.